# Webgrid checkbox onchange to add to dictionary

Tags: c#, javascript, dictionary, checkbox

Currently using a webgrid

```
@{
                    var DB = Database.Open("CHAVI");
                    var grid = new WebGrid(DB.Query("SELECT [FileTrackingTag], FileID FROM (SELECT [FileTrackingTag], FileID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [FileTrackingTag] ORDER BY FileID) rn FROM [dbo].[MasterSequence]) t WHERE rn=1 ORDER BY [FileTrackingTag]"));
                    @grid.GetHtml(
                        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column(header: "Assign? ", style: "labelcolumn",
                                    format:
                                        @<text><input class="check-box" id="assignChkBx" name="assignChkBx" type="checkbox" value="@item.FileTrackingTag" onchange='handleChange(this);'  /></text>),
                            grid.Column("FileTrackingTag", "FileTrackingTag")
                            )
                    )
                 }
```

And I have a hiddenfield

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyHiddenDict)
```

from my model

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MyHiddenDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I need a javascript function that will add or remove to the dictionary based off if the checkbox is checked or not.  My first approach was to add it to a string that was comma delimited.  However, I have no way of undoing it if the user unclicks the checkbox.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to just force the user to select only from one page, otherwise you need to create a list in the sessionstate and when you call the webgrid page check off the ones you already used